# GIT when saving file changes are lost

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have a GIT repository set up with visual studio and committing and syncing goes fine when I pull a branch. However when I restart my computer the changed suddenly start to do odd.

If i edit a file and do not save it I can commit the changes within visual studio. However if I hit "ctrl + S"  it suddenly marks it as up-to-date and forgets all the changes i made. not though that the changes in the file are still there.

A workaround I have been using but which is utterly cumbersome is to close the edited file, reopen it add a space and commit it.

If i recreate a new local branch it will work again for another day. but once the computer restart i get the same problem.

Does anyone know why GIT + visual studio would be doing this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably not a problem of Git, but Visual Studio, maybe you should report a bug to MS.

Comment: I think that could be right, I'm using Visual studio 2015 community edition. I have reported it to Microsoft but no reply yet so far. Therefore I thought let's see whether anyone had the same problem on stack overflow. thanks for your insight as well though.

Answer (score -2):

It turned out to be an issue in the Git ignore file which wasn't excluded. So if you have a .gitignore file make sure it doesn't get send to the repository.

Comment: You generally *do* want the .gitignore to be sent to the repository to ensure that ignored files are consistent across all development machines...